# MiGS payment gateway is not appearing in Payment Methods section in One Page Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I am using this [MiGS Payment Gateway plugin](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/migs-payment-gateway.html). I input all fields in the plugin settings ( System > Configuration > Payment Methods > MIGS Payment Gateway ) and enabled the settings. I use One Page Checkout and disabled Multishipping.

However, after I pressed Checkout > Checkout as Guest > filled in basic information, address, shipping method. However, when I reached Step 5, it said:

> Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no payment methods available for it.

What did I miss ? Anything I should provide for you guys to debug?

Using Magento 1.9.1

---

**UPDATE** I updated the `info.phtml` of `app/design/frontend/{theme_name}/{package_name}/template/checkout/onepage/payment/` to have the following codes:

```
$payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
$methods = array(array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('--Please Select--')));
foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
    $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
    $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
        'label'   => $paymentTitle,
        'value' => $paymentCode,
    );
}
print_r($methods);
```

It successfully shows the MIGS as "Active methods". Why does One Page Checkout not available to show payment methods?

The output of the `print_r()` is as follow:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [value] => [label] => --Please Select-- ) 
  [free] => Array ( [label] => No Payment Information Required [value] => free ) 
  [purchaseorder] => Array ( [label] => Purchase Order [value] => purchaseorder ) 
  [banktransfer] => Array ( [label] => Bank Transfer [value] => banktransfer )
  [cashondelivery] => Array ( [label] => Cash On Delivery [value] => cashondelivery ) 
  [hosted_pro] => Array ( [label] => Paid by Credit Card [value] => hosted_pro ) 
  [migsvpc_server] => Array ( [label] => MiGS [value] => migsvpc_server )
  [paypal_here] => Array ( [label] => Credit Card Payment [value] => paypal_here ) 
)
```

---

**UPDATE** I further found out that when I click "Next" in Shipping Method, the request to `saveShippingMethod/` returns an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getGiftMessageId() on a non-object in /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/GiftMessage/Model/Observer.php on line 137

Comment: **Compatible with: 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2.0, 1.7**  you must read before install the extension

Comment: The Q&A said it's compatible with 1.9 also

Comment: extension is shown in admin? and did you refresh the cache and give file permission?

Comment: Yes, cleared cache, disabled compilation & the extension is shown in System > Configuration > Payment Methods correctly.

Comment: use this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/migs-vpc-payment-method-integration.html

Comment: I tried also this extension quite a while before. Can't make it working. Maybe I should try one more time.

Comment: i use this extension in one project and working without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this extension for mig payment

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/migs-vpc-payment-method-integration.html

only one thing is this extension on sandbox mode it always show the **KWD 1** order total don't worry about that.

[image]

Comment: Tried to use this extension. Enabled "MIGS VPC Server Hosted" (and filled in  appropriate information, such as Access Code and Secure Hash Secret) and cleared cache, but the one page checkout of Magento still said no payment method available.

Comment: Additionally, I enabled Cash of Delivery and Purchase Order to cross-check whether the One Page Checkout is behaving normal or not. After I enabled these payment methods, the Checkout page still shows no payment method available. How come? Is is possible the theme restricted payment method?

Comment: @Raptor disabled the other extension then check.. or try on default there

Comment: the Magento didn't enable other third party extensions; only the default ones are installed. Still cannot figure out why.

Comment: One thing I found out that if I picked Default Store View in Configuration, the MIGS disappears from "Payment Methods". Is that normal?

Comment: the payment method is defined in `<default>` tag so it's configuration only showing in default configuration.

Comment: thx @Qaisar, I have just updated the question. I found that the payment method can be shown via `getActiveMethods()`, but cannot be shown in One Page Checkout by default. How can I know why?

Comment: @Raptor i added my configuration check what you are missing..

Comment: my configuration is similar to you, but I disabled the Creditmax part. After I enabled Creditmax, it's still the same.

Comment: Also, I found out that the only currency accepted & installed in Hong Kong Dollars (HKD). Does it relate to the problem? I think MiGS accepts multiple currencies ?

Comment: @Raptor if you adding test credential then it is not problem other currency may be set in mings account but i work with test credential so no idea about that

Comment: End up I found that the previous author of the theme manually set the payment method to `hosted_pro` ( PayPal ).  After I changed his codes, I am able to change the payment method to MiGS ( though a lot of problems still exist , now encountering HTTP Status 400 ) . I will create a new question to ask this